# Siri on macOS behind a corporate proxy

Tags: mac, siri, proxy, macos

I'm running into a an issue where Siri can't connect to her servers from behind our corporate proxy connection. What's interesting is that this isn't an issue on our iPhones behind the same proxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess they're contacting different servers and the macOS ones are being blocked somewhere in your org's network. I'm not positive of that, though.

Comment: Agree with @tubedogg.  Your iPhone might not be able to use it on wifi so it's switching to cellular to contact the Apple servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manage a Squid proxy for my organisation and when I try to use Siri in Sierra, the following log entries are recorded:

```
1474540244.610      0 macos-sierra-host.local TAG_NONE/400 4410 NONE error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

Not entirely sure what it is requesting, so time to break out the tcpdump-hammer I guess. I'll report back if I have any more insights.

**EDIT 1 - 22-Sep-2016 10:58 UTC**

Looks like Siri isn't using a valid URL when requesting via a proxy. Here's the HTTP headers from Squid after a Siri connection is attempted:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/3.5.20
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 10:42:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4064
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.local
Via: 1.1 proxy.local (squid/3.5.20)
Connection: close
```

The details in the error message (sent from Squid but never seen by the user) are:

> **Invalid Request error was encountered while trying to process the
>   request:**
>
> `&# 22;&#  3;&#  1;`
>
> Some possible problems are:
>
> - Missing or unknown request method.
> - Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0).
> - Request is too large.
> - Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests.
> - Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.
> - HTTP/1.1 Expect: feature is being asked from an HTTP/1.0 software.

So - looks like some more tcpdump-hammer in my future as I try to find what this original requst looks like (where it's going etc). Stay tuned.

**EDIT 2 - 22-Sep-2016 11:16 UTC**

The problem is Siri is using TCP/443 but not using HTTPS. Consequently, a HTTP proxy like Squid will choke on these connections. The good news is I've identified the outbound connections from Siri are resolving an A record for `origin.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net` and then connecting to it on port 443. At this point it initiates a TLS handshake and the rest is encrypted. So, thanks Apple for encrypting it, but FU for using a reserved port for non-HTTPS traffic. Seriously - WTF?!

**Here's a solution**

I've poked around many (*many*) DNS queries and it seems they all resolve `origin.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net` in the `17.252.0.0/16` address range - this is a slice of Apple's broader `17.0.0.0/8` range. This should allow you to send anything destined for `17.252.0.0` direct (either via proxy config or PAC/WPAD). Unfortunately, this may also gobble up other traffic that you don't want bypassing your proxy too :-/

Until Apple decide to use a real HTTPS protocol for Siri on Sierra or, use a different port (unlike the current hijacking of TCP/443!!!), we're pretty much screwed.

Comment: No worries Coby. I've tried a few different mechanisms to send clients directly (WPAD/PAC file, ACLs, even manual client side proxy exceptions) but Siri seems to use the proxy regardless. The only way I can get Siri to work on Sierra is to disable the proxy config completely on the client. I spoke with a friend who has worked on the Siri implementation at Apple and they are aware (*apparently*)...whether that translates to "**action**" we'll have to wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution for the pac file:

> ```
> if (
>    (shExpMatch(url, "*guzzoni.apple.com*")) ||
>    (shExpMatch(url, "*.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net*"))
> )
> return "DIRECT";
> ```

Source: http://blog.mansshardt.net/siri-ios-macos-hinter-squid-proxy-zum-laufen-bringen/

Comment: The domain `guzzoni.apple.com` is what I needed to whitelist in my case.  For me, it resolves to `guzzoni-apple-com.v.aaplimg.com`

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer as a "where to start looking"...

There's a comprehensive list of port numbers used by Apple at
[Apple KB : TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](https://support.apple.com/HT202944)
[too much to copy here]

You can also pretty much open the entire 17.x.x.x address space, as it's all owned by Apple.

It claims Siri only needs port 443, https/SSL [which I'd imagine would be open anyway]

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm James' findings at my org: Siri (macOS) only works with proxy disabled.  We're using a different proxy product (via PAC file, FYI), but same results.  Tested using public release of macOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C68).

@Tetsujin - Despite the "Jan 8, 2017", Apple has not updated it to include "Siri (macOS)"; they currently only specify "Siri (iOS)".  To paraphrase James' comment, "this is not your iPhone's Siri".

Also, if his Squid logs are correct and `origin.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net` is what Siri (macOS) uses; then the wildcard exemption for Apple's 17.0.0.0/8 would be moot (per the "akadns.net" domain).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by putting privoxy in front of squid. I have no idea why it works, mind you, but it does work reliably. I can share config files if you want.
I did try WPAD/PAC before, but Siri does not comply and goes through squid anyway.

Comment: Not an answer, just trying to get to the right direction... might help someone else out? I have spent 3 days trying to figure this out (Siri + squid proxy). I've even configured squid to allow all IPs and Ports (1-65k), and Siri is the only thing that will not work. I am interested in Phtagn's solution of using privoxy. Would love to see config files if he/she is still around.